# React-select dropdown options slow on select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have this function that gets data from an API to be shown for selection in `react-select`. It gets so slow/drags. I tried looking at the solutions given here on stackoverflow but haven't been able to modify them to suit my use case.

```
const getItems = async () => {
    await Axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/items/available/${myItem}`)
        .then((response) => {
            const items = response.data.map((item) => ({ label: item.name, value: item.id }));
            setItemOptions(items);
        }
}
```

This is how I tried to make the modifications

```
<Select filter={createFilter({ ignoreAccents: false })} filterOption={createFilter({ ignoreAccents: false })} isMulti options={itemOptions} />
```

***DISCLAIMER: I'm learning react doing a project, so I'm new to it.***

Comment: Have you tried reducing the number of options? Appears to be API rendering overload.

Comment: less than 1000 options only

Comment: I just loaded many options but it works without problem https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-monad-k0kxp0/ . I think you have problem in other functions which we don't see here.

Comment: You might have throttle on for some reason